# Derive `Deserialize` with borrowed struct field

Tags: rust, macros, deserialization, traits

I'm trying to derive `Deserialize` on a struct that has borrowed content:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyS<'a> {
    pub addr: &'a SocketAddr,
}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cb925dcdb4fb8391cd63d7e0d6cb4ca6)

I get the following compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&'a std::net::SocketAddr: _::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     pub addr: &'a SocketAddr,
  |     ^^^ the trait `_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `&'a std::net::SocketAddr`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <std::net::SocketAddr as _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>>
  = note: required by `_::_serde::de::SeqAccess::next_element`
```

**What are the different ways I can get this struct to implement `Deserialize` for some lifetime ?**

Note: I don't actually require the deserialization to be zero-copy, it's only a nice-to-have

Comment: Deserializing into a reference isn't really possible, as nobody owns the data. See this Github issue: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1092

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this, and here's why:

Serde allows for zero-copy deserialization of certain types. In this case, the data is borrowed from the `Deserializer`, which in turn either borrows or owns a buffer of some kind. Since `&[u8]` and `&str` are both fundamentally streams of bytes, they can just be deserialized as references into the buffer. How exactly this works is explained in the [serde docs](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html), but it fundamentally requires that the Rust type is laid out exactly as the data exists in the buffer you are deserializing.

In your case, however, you want to deserialize a `SocketAddr`. The problem is that the data in the buffer is in a different form from the data you want to borrow. Serde serializes a `SocketAddr`s into a string via `Display`, see for example [this implemention](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.115/src/serde/ser/impls.rs.html#734-747) for `SocketAddrV4`. But a `SocketAddr` itself is stored as a 32 bit integer and a 16 bit integer. You cannot borrow one as the other; some kind of parsing needs to happen, and someone then needs to own the resulting data. Serde logically has your struct own that data. Even in binary serialization, there is no guarantee the layout of the serialized data will match the layout of the struct, so parsing needs to happen.

This is encoded in the type system via the implementations of `Deserialize` serde provides. [This page](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.115/serde/trait.Deserialize.html) has the full list. You can see that there is an implementation for `&'a str` where the lifetime of the `Deserializer` (`'de`) outlives `'a`. There is no implementation for references to most other types, including `&SocketAddr`.

This serde issue [linked by PitaJ](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1092) shows a good minimal code example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I had seen hints that it was impossible, but all related to specific cases, where I didn't understand if it really applied to the general case / to my case.

Comment: "someone then needs to the resulting data". I suppose you mean "own" ? This is kind of the key sentence to your explanation

Comment: Side questions: in the case of deserializing into a `&'a str` (which is possible), where the `Deserializer` (`'de`) outlives `'a`, how is the Deserializer kept around for as long as the struct ? On the heap ? Does this mean it lives much longer than the Deserialization process ? And if my struct owns its fields, is the Deserializer destroyed right after deserializing ?

Comment: Yes, I did mean "own". Fixed, thanks! As for questions about the lifetime of the `Deserializer`, it will depend on the serde companion library. You'll notice that serde defines no actual Deseralizers, just traits. In the case of serde_json we have `pub fn from_str<'a, T>(s: &'a str) -> Result<T> where T: Deserialize<'a>` which skips over the `'de` lifetime entirely. Your data gets a borrow on the buffer itself. This is also possible with intermediary Deserializer, at least in this library. Pressing the [src] button on the docs is a great way to find out how this is done...

Comment: But in general, a well-made library will allow you to throw out the Deserializer and keep the reference to the buffer of data. Serde is designed to allow this. When the Deserializer is destroyed is always subject to Rust's ordinary drop rules. Serde doesn't necessitate allocation of Deserializers. Allocation will only occur if you deserialize into a type that needs it, like `Vec`, `HashMap`, or `String`.